# @font-face not finding fonts in folder

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

I am trying to get @font-face to work within a sub domain located in the folder public_html/evansopen. I have the site http://coryfitzpatrick.com/evansopen/ running. I want to put fontsquirrel files in evansopen/fonts but they wont load when I dont have them in the same location as the styles.css and index.php (The public_html/evansopen folder). It is running fine this way currently, but I like to keep my file structure clean.

I can get images to load from /evansopen/images/putting_green_footer.gif folder with no problem like this

```
#footer {
    background-image: url(images/putting_green_footer.gif); background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Why can I not get @font-face to direct to evansopen/fonts/ like so?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'nexa_lightregular';
        src: url('fonts/nexa_light-webfont.eot');
        src: url('fonts/nexa_light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
             url('fonts/nexa_light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('fonts/nexa_light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('fonts/nexa_light-webfont.svg#nexa_lightregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I have researched this quite a bit. Im sorry if this is a redundant post.

Comment: If your fonts folder isn't in the same folder as your css file then this won't work. I'm guessing your fonts folder is split from your main www folder so try /fonts/nexa_light-webfont.eot instead of fonts/nexa_light-webfont.eot.

Comment: The fonts folder is in the same location as the style.css file. The paths are: public_html/evansopen/styles.css & public_html/evansopen/fonts/nexa_light-webfont.eot.

Comment: Well I would try putting in the complete path of the font files like http://coryfitzpatrick.com/evansopen/fonts/nexa_light-webfont.eot and also I don't believe you need quotes around the font-family: 'nexa_lightregular'; try font-family: nexa_lightregular;

Answer (score 5):

**Example to using** `fontface`

Your CSS file (domain.com/path/custom-font.css)

```
font-family: 'nexa_lightregular';
      src: url('fonts/nexa_light-webfont.eot');
      src: url('fonts/nexa_light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
           url('fonts/nexa_light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
           url('fonts/nexa_light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
           url('fonts/nexa_light-webfont.svg#nexa_lightregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

Your font files have to upload in

> domain.com/path/**fonts**/nexa_light-webfont.ttf

for example

PS : It's about where is your `css` file, so make a `/fonts/` folder in same CSS file path.

EX: domain.com/mycss.css -> domain.com/fonts/myfont.ttf

Comment: I have the fonts folder in the same location as styles.css. The paths are: public_html/evansopen/styles.css & public_html/evansopen/fonts/nexa_light-webfont.eot

Comment: What about subdomain? And a child theme? I put some website in subdomain, and use a child theme for it.